# Error Code 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1241

delete from invoices
where client_id = (
select*
from clients
where name = 'Myworks'
);

I'm trying to delete a row of data for a client from another table called invoices, but it throws me an error 1241. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
where client_id = ( select* from clients where name = 'Myworks' )
```

If that `clients` table has more than one column, which column should `client_id` be compared to?  MySQL doesn't know, and won't decide for you, and so it's giving you an error message.

Specify *one* column for that identifier:

```
where client_id = ( select client_id from clients where name = 'Myworks' )
```

(This is assuming the target column is also called `client_id`.  Use whatever column you wish.)

As an aside, using `=` there is weird to me.  I'm not sure if the system supports it, it may and this may be a non-issue.  But if it doesn't, use `IN` instead.  (Which just makes more sense to me semantically anyway.)  For example:

```
where client_id IN ( select client_id from clients where name = 'Myworks' )
```

Comment: As long as the subquery returns a single row which happens to have only one column, using the `=` operator is allowed. But I agree with you it makes more sense to use `IN` and specify the column insead of using wildcard.